# get latitude & longitude as per address given for leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In my project I am using leaflet to display points.

I am getting address from my database & want to show point for that particular address.

I haven't found anything which will give me latitude & longitude as per address provided.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 32):

If you want to use OpenStreetmaps for this, you can simply make a request (using jquery):

```
    $.get(location.protocol + '//nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q='+address, function(data){
       console.log(data);
    });
```

You'll get JSON objects containing (not only) lat and lon.

Comment: this is free? unlimite request?

Comment: **14 MARGARET AV,EVERETT,Ontario,L0M1J0,Canada**
This address is not found

Answer (score 19):

solution without additional plugins. only Leaflet and pure JavaScript. dragging the marker or entering an address gives you coordinates. if you have problems with the nominatim request just change https to http.
demo here : http://yellowthailand.com/leafletgeo.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Leaflet Address Lookup and Coordinates</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { width:100%;padding:0;margin:0; }
.container { width:95%;max-width:980px;padding:1% 2%;margin:0 auto }
#lat, #lon { text-align:right }
#map { width:100%;height:50%;padding:0;margin:0; }
.address { cursor:pointer }
.address:hover { color:#AA0000;text-decoration:underline }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<b>Coordinates</b>
<form>
<input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" size=12 value="">
<input type="text" name="lon" id="lon" size=12 value="">
</form>

<b>Address Lookup</b>
<div id="search">
<input type="text" name="addr" value="" id="addr" size="58" />
<button type="button" onclick="addr_search();">Search</button>
<div id="results"></div>
</div>

<br />

<div id="map"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// New York
var startlat = 40.75637123;
var startlon = -73.98545321;

var options = {
 center: [startlat, startlon],
 zoom: 9
}

document.getElementById('lat').value = startlat;
document.getElementById('lon').value = startlon;

var map = L.map('map', options);
var nzoom = 12;

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: 'OSM'}).addTo(map);

var myMarker = L.marker([startlat, startlon], {title: "Coordinates", alt: "Coordinates", draggable: true}).addTo(map).on('dragend', function() {
 var lat = myMarker.getLatLng().lat.toFixed(8);
 var lon = myMarker.getLatLng().lng.toFixed(8);
 var czoom = map.getZoom();
 if(czoom < 18) { nzoom = czoom + 2; }
 if(nzoom > 18) { nzoom = 18; }
 if(czoom != 18) { map.setView([lat,lon], nzoom); } else { map.setView([lat,lon]); }
 document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
 document.getElementById('lon').value = lon;
 myMarker.bindPopup("Lat " + lat + "<br />Lon " + lon).openPopup();
});

function chooseAddr(lat1, lng1)
{
 myMarker.closePopup();
 map.setView([lat1, lng1],18);
 myMarker.setLatLng([lat1, lng1]);
 lat = lat1.toFixed(8);
 lon = lng1.toFixed(8);
 document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
 document.getElementById('lon').value = lon;
 myMarker.bindPopup("Lat " + lat + "<br />Lon " + lon).openPopup();
}

function myFunction(arr)
{
 var out = "<br />";
 var i;

 if(arr.length > 0)
 {
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
   out += "<div class='address' title='Show Location and Coordinates' onclick='chooseAddr(" + arr[i].lat + ", " + arr[i].lon + ");return false;'>" + arr[i].display_name + "</div>";
  }
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = out;
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Sorry, no results...";
 }

}

function addr_search()
{
 var inp = document.getElementById("addr");
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&limit=3&q=" + inp.value;
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
   {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    myFunction(myArr);
   }
 };
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15):

There is a great geocoder already developed for Leaflet.

https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch

You can use the results easily like

```
map.on('geosearch_showlocation', function (result) {
    L.marker([result.x, result.y]).addTo(map)
});
```

Comment: I want to pass Address & in return want to get latitute & longitute. Is there any api which does this.

Comment: Correct.That's what this Plugin does. You enter in a address and it finds out the geo coordinates of that. You access said geodata in the event fired data.(result above)

Comment: If you are saying you want to bypass user input and do it directly with code, that's simple too. just use `control.geosearch('New York, NY')`

Comment: can you provide example of it.

Comment: I want to get street name by latLng, how can i do it?

Comment: @AndréVicente reverse geocoding is still an open issue on this plugin(https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch/pull/25), you may want to look into others http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding

Comment: @snkashis Hi. Is still work in version 3.2.1 using 'geosearch_showlocation'? If not how do I do that in latest version? Thanks

Comment: How I would save the latitude and longitude searched in a table to be show?

Answer (score 1):

One more solution without using any plugins. I am reading the data from the Mongo DB and then use Javascript, Angular(not necessaril ) and Leaflet libraries to draw the marker for the coordinates that we get from the Mongo DB.

**HTML**

Just displaying the leaflet div and the onclick event where we pass the date and email of a user. This information will be passed to the MongoDB to fetch the set of latitudes and longitudes of the user for the given time frame

```
<div class="map" leaflet [leafletOptions]="historicalOptions">
        <div *ngFor="let l of historicalLayers" [leafletLayer]="l"></div>
      </div>

<div class="col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <button type="button" (click)="getHistoricalData(onDate,fromTime,toTime,user.email)" class="btn btn-primary p-4">
            Get Map
          </button>
        </div>
```

**Code**

```
ngOnInit() {

this.historicalOptions = {
  layers: [
    tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '...' }),
    this.heatmapLayer
  ],
  center: latLng(xxxxxxx, xxxxxxx),
  zoom: 16
};
}

public getHistoricalData(onDate: Date, fromTime: Date, toTime: Date, userEmail) {

this.historicalLayers = [];
this.apiService.getGPSLocations(fromDate.toISOString(), toDate.toISOString(), userEmail)
    .subscribe(data => {

      if (data && data.length) {

        const markerLayers = this.drawMarkerPlotline(data, 'blue');
        this.historicalLayers = markerLayers;

      }
    }
}

private drawMarkerPlotline(data, color) {
if (data) {
  let rawData;
  if (typeof data === 'string')
    rawData = JSON.parse(data);
  else
    rawData = data;
  const layers = [];
  if (rawData.length) {
    this.heatmapData.data = [];
    rawData.forEach((point, index) => {
      if (point && point.sensorValue && point.sensorValue.attr_lat && point.sensorValue.attr_lng) {
        const markerLayer = marker([point.sensorValue.attr_lat, point.sensorValue.attr_lng], {
          icon: icon({
            iconSize: [15, 15],
            iconAnchor: [7, 7],
            iconUrl: this.getIconPath(color)
          }),
          title: new Date(point.observationTimestamp).toLocaleString(),
        });
        markerLayer.userId = point.userAccount.userId;

        layers.push(markerLayer);

        this.heatmapData.data.push({
          lat: point.sensorValue.attr_lat,
          lng: point.sensorValue.attr_lng,
          // count: 1
        });
      }
    });
    this.heatmapLayer.setData(this.heatmapData);

    return [layerGroup(layers)];
  }
}
return null;
}

private getIconPath(color) {
let icon: string;
switch (color) {
  case 'green':
    icon = 'assets/green-circle.png'
    break;
  case 'orange':
    icon = 'assets/orange-circle.png'
    break;
  default:
    icon = 'assets/blue-circle.png'
    break;
}
return icon;
}
```

**Note**

Code snippets are directly taken from my sample application. Hence make changes wherever required in order to suit your requirements.