# LeafletJS :Search box outside the map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, esri

Currently I have this `leaflet.js` map

`<div id="myMap" style="width: 100%; height:300px;"></div>`

```
<script>
// This setup the leafmap object by linking the map() method to the map id (in <div> html element)
var map = L.map('myMap', {
center: [14.599512, 120.984222],
zoom: 13,
// minZoom: 1.5,
//  maxZoom: 1.5
});

// Start adding controls as follow... L.controlName().addTo(map);

// Control 1: This add the OpenStreetMap background tile
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


// Control 2: This add a scale to the map
L.control.scale().addTo(map);

// Control 3: This add a Search bar
var searchControl = new L.esri.Controls.Geosearch().addTo(map);


var results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

searchControl.on('results', function(data){
    results.clearLayers();
    for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
    }
});
```

this is the current output of this code.

[image]

This is working fine as of now. But What I'm trying to do is to make a search box outside the `leaflet map`. When the user type some places on the search box outside the map, the map will automatically find the value of searchbox.

This is my current `mdb html code` I don't have idea how to do that.

```
  <!--Grid row-->
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="md-form mb-0">
            <input type="text" id="proj_loc" name="proj_loc" class="form-control">
            <label for="proj_loc" class="">Location</label>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <!--Grid row-->
```

[image]

Comment: This thread gives me an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919227/get-latitude-longitude-as-per-address-given-for-leaflet

Answer (score 5):

Please check **[Leaflet Control Search](https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/)** Plugin for adding search control.

```
map.addControl( new L.Control.Search({
    container: 'findbox',
    layer: markersLayer,
    initial: false,
    collapsed: false
}) );
```

For example please check [this](https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/outside.html)
You will get full code [here](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It is in the documentation that you posted, but remember to add a div with the 'findbox' as its id either before or after the map id.                                                                                                                             <div id='findbox'></div><div id="myMap" style="width: 100%; height:300px;"></div>