# Geocoder API - To get a Lat,Lng from a Physical Address

Tags: geocode

We try to use leaflet map and exploring the options. One question is any options available in your API to get the Lat, Lng from a Physical address? Please advise. This option is very useful for us.

Thanks,

Comment: There is already another similar post  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919227/get-latitude-longitude-as-per-address-given-for-leaflet